# How to force the user to type current password to change password with Spring Security

Tags: hash, spring-security, passwords

I have a Spring Project what I use `Spring Security 4.0.1.RELEASE`, the password is being encrypted with `org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder`.

The Password Encoder class is:

```
public class PasswordEncoder {

    public static String hashPassword(final String password) {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return passwordEncoder.encode(password);
    }
}
```

I have a `Change Password` page that I want to make the user type the current password to be able to change his password, but when I try to match the password it never works because the encrypted new typed password (that is the same as his password) does not match with the encrypted password in the database.

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Why is your "Change Password" feature called "Reset Password"? Those are two totally different things.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan it's a Change Password, don't bother with the naming.

Comment: If you want to verify a stored bcrypt password, you need to retrieve the password in order to get the salt.